# Sequelize Eager Load attributes in relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model that looks like this:

```
let Family = sequelize.define('Family', {
   name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }});
let Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
   firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
   lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }});
let  PersonFamily = sequelize.define('PersonFamily', {
   extraInfo: { type: DataTypes.JSONB }});
let  Relationship = sequelize.define('Relationship', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }});

Relationship.hasMany(PersonFamily);
PersonFamily.belongsTo(Relationship, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false } });
Person.belongsToMany(Family, { through: PersonFamily, as: 'families' });
Family.belongsToMany(Person, { through: PersonFamily, as: 'members' });
```

I want to pull out all the families with all their members and the relationship they have. I tried this:

```
Family.findById(fid,{include: [{model:Person ,as: 'members'}]} 
//works but does not pull the relationship name
```

and this

```
Family.findById(fid,{include: [{model:Person ,as: 'members', include: PersonFamily}]} 
//does not work ... error
```

Any idea how can I pull relationship name also ?

Comment: try `Family.findById(fid,{include: [{model:Person ,as: 'members', include: {model:PersonFamily, as:'families'}}]}`

Comment: @Shivam it says PersonFamily is not associated to Person

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using

Comment: @Shivam version 4.3.2